# How to cache a different page version based on HTTP header?

Tags: cache, performance, plugin-w3-total-cache

My website has an HTTP response header generated by Cloudflare that contain the visitor country code, and i can use that header in PHP to generate a dynamic content based on the visitor country, now i'm wondering how to use page caching to cache several version of the page depend on the visitor country without using ajax.